# How to get rid of duplicate numbers

Tags: javascript

I want to make a function that makes a random number and puts it in an array , then checks if the number is inside the array ,if it is i want the function to make a new number till it makes a number that isn't in the array yet.

**I've checked the other ways to resolve this and I want a solution in this way .. and by checking i mean making a function with a set option.. and etc..**

```
 var checkR = [,1];
    for (var i = 0; i < randomImages.length; i++)
    {
        var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 56);
        checkR.push(random);
        for (var j = 1; j < randomImages.length+1; j++) {
          
            if (checkR[i]==checkR[j])
                i--;
    
        }
    }
```

in this way it will go into an infinite loop.....

Answer (score 1):

You can take a `Set` to keep the numbers which will always maintain a set of unique numbers only.

```js
let uniqueSet = new Set();
randomImages = [1,2,3,4,5]

while (randomImages.length != uniqueSet.size)
    {
        var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 56);
        uniqueSet.add(random);
    }
    
console.log([...uniqueSet]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
/**
 * @description add unique random number to array.
 *
 * @author Ernesto Jara Olveda
 * @date 06/07/2021
 * @param {number[]} arr array of unique values.
 * @returns {number[]} the array with a new value.
 */
function createRandomNumber (arr) {
    const uniques = new Set(arr);
    const l = uniques.size;

    let newNumber;
    do {
        newNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*(10+l));
    } while(uniques.has(newNumber));

    uniques.add(newNumber);

    return [...uniques]
}

var list =[1,3,4,5,6,78];

list = createRandomNumber(list);
console.log(list);

for (let e=0; e<100; e++) {
list = createRandomNumber(list);
}

const sorter = (a,b) =>{
  if (a>b)return 1;
  if (a<b)return -1;
}
//you can sort them just to make sure
console.log(list.sort(sorter))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, so not sure the following will work:

```
var checkR = [];
for (var i = 0; i < randomImages.length; i++) {
   var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 56);
   if(!checkR.includes(random)) { // this will check for duplicate data
      checkR.push(random);
   }
   // your remaining code
 }
```

Comment: i want to build an array without duplicates **not** in a set way , but to decrement i .

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, you can use this. This resembles the logic you already have

```js
const checkR = [];
const randomImages = [];

for (let i = 0; i < randomImages.length; i++) {
    const random = genUniqueRandomNumber(checkR, randomImages.length);
    checkR.push(random);
}

function genUniqueRandomNumber(check, multiplier) {
    let random = genRandomNumber();
    let attempts = 0;
    const exists = check.indexOf(random) > -1;

    if (!exists) {
        return random;
    }

    random = null;
    const MAX_ATTEMPTS = 1000;
    // if a random number exists in check array
    // and no of regeneration attempts is less than MAX_ATTEMPTS
    // generate a new random number
    while (check.indexOf(random) > -1 && attempts <= MAX_ATTEMPTS) {
        random = genRandomNumber(multiplier);
        attempts++;
    }

    if (random == null) {
        throw new Error(`Failed to find a unique random number after exhausting all ${MAX_ATTEMPTS} attempts`);
    }

    return random;
}

function genRandomNumber(multiplier = 56) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * multiplier);
}
```

Comment: i got an error:
Uncaught Error: Failed to find a unique random number after exhausting all 1000 attempts
    at genUniqueRandomNumber (JavaScript.js:49)
    at JavaScript.js:25

Comment: Yes, this is expected as we do not want to let the loop run infinitely. What is your use case by the way? Do you want to display random images?

Answer (score 0):

```
 var checkR = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
 var done = false
     //  console.log(checkR)
 for (var x of checkR) {
     var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
     checkR.push(random)
         //  console.log(checkR)


     function checkele() {
         for (var j = 0; j < checkR.length - 1; j++) {
             if (checkR[j] == random) {
                 done = false
                 break
             } else {
                 done = true
             }
         }
         return done === true ? true : false
     }

     let c = checkele()

     if (c) {
         console.log(`${random} is not in the array`)
         break;
     } else {
         continue
     }


 }
```